# How to find out if scrollView is about to be scrolled up or down

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, scrollview

I would like to find out if a scrollView is scrolled up or down. Ideally, I'd like to have only one call if the scrollView is scrolled up or down. I tried this but it will obviously not tell me anything about the direction:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"%.2f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

contentOffset will always be 0 - it doesn't matter whether I scrolled up or down. Now I could simply check in -(void)scrollViewDidScroll: if the offset is positive or negative, but this is called constantly. scrollViewWillBeginDragging has the advantage of being called only once and this is what I need. Is there something like scrollViewDidBeginDragging? I didn't find anything in the docs. Any smart workaround?

Comment: What if the user puts their finger down, starts scrolling down, then changes their mind and scrolls up?

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek If he scrolls < 0, then I would need to cancel the action which I called when he scrolled > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a declared property to let us know that the tableview is starting to scroll.  Let's use a BOOL called `scrollViewJustStartedScrolling`.

In `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` set it to true:

```
self.scrollViewJustStartedScrolling = YES;
```

In `scrollViewDidScroll` do something like:

```
if (self.scrollViewJustStartedScrolling) {
    // check contentOffset and do what you need to do.
    self.scrollViewJustStartedScrolling = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Store the initial content offset in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:`

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.initialContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.previousContentDelta = 0.f;
}
```

And check it on each `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat prevDelta = self.previousContentDelta;
    CGFloat delta = scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.initialContentOffset;
    if (delta > 0.f && prevDelta <= 0.f) {
        // started scrolling positively
    } else if (delta < 0.f && prevDelta >= 0.f) {
        // started scrolling negatively
    }
    self.previousContentDelta = delta;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to store the initialContentOffset since it will always be 0.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I forgot all about users wanting to change their mind in the middle of their touch. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Inafziger `contentOffset` is not the offset from the beginning of the scroll, it's the offset of the whole scroll view. If it were to always be zero at the beginning of a drag, why would we be concerned about possibly scrolling up?

Comment: True!  +1 for the solution which allows them to reverse direction.

Answer (score 4):

It **IS** possible to perform this check in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` before any scrolling is registered. (IOS 5+). By examining the scroll view's built-in pan gesture recognizer you can check gesture direction.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{ 
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];

    if(translation.y > 0)
    {
        // react to dragging down
    } else
    {
        // react to dragging up
    }
}
```

I found it very useful in canceling out of a scroll at the very first drag move when the user is dragging in a forbidden direction.

Comment: **Note, the translation can return zero if the gesture is too subtle.** Use ```CGPoint velocity = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:scrollView.superview];``` instead.

Comment: Furthermore note, if you flick a UIScrollView and then touch and hold while the view is still decelerating, scrollViewWillBeginDragging will be called with translation and velocity both having x = y = 0. So better do not assume that ```else{…}``` would be ```dragging left```. Check for translation/velocity values of zero to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{

    if (velocity.y > 0){
        NSLog(@"up");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"down");
    }
}
```